# PHP & SQL Server: how to insert data into 2 tables and insert multiple rows

Tags: php, sql-server, post, sqlsrv

***I am trying to enter data from html into MSSQL database using php. I am unable to insert record in 2 different tables and unable to insert multiple records to a table, I have the code below***

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];

$email = $_POST["email"];

$company = $_POST["company"];

$contact = (int)$_POST["contact"];

$worktitle = $_POST["worktitle"];

$industry = $_POST["industry"];

$V101 = $_POST["part2q1"];    
$V102 = $_POST["part2q2"];    
$V103 = $_POST["part2q3"];    
$V104 = $_POST["part2q4"];    
$V105 = $_POST["part2q5"];    
$V106 = $_POST["part2q6"];    
$V107 = $_POST["part3q1"];    
$V108 = $_POST["part3q2"];    
$V109 = $_POST["part3q3"];    
$V110 = $_POST["part3q4"];    
$V111 = $_POST["part3q5"];    
$V112 = $_POST["part3q6"];    
$V113 = $_POST["part4q1"];    
$V114 = $_POST["part4q2"];    
$V115 = $_POST["part4q3"];    
$V116 = $_POST["part4q4"];    
$V117 = $_POST["part4q5"];    
$V118 = $_POST["part4q6"];    
$V119 = $_POST["part5q1"];    
$V120 = $_POST["part5q2"];    
$V121 = $_POST["part5q3"];    
$V122 = $_POST["part5q4"];    
$V123 = $_POST["part5q5"];    
$V124 = $_POST["part5q6"];    
$V125 = $_POST["part6q1"];    
$V126 = $_POST["part6q2"];    
$V127 = $_POST["part6q3"];    
$V128 = $_POST["part6q4"];    
$V129 = $_POST["part6q5"];    
$V130 = $_POST["part6q6"];    
$V131 = $_POST["part7q1"];    
$V132 = $_POST["part7q2"];    
$V133 = $_POST["part7q3"];    
$V134 = $_POST["part7q4"];    
$V135 = $_POST["part7q5"];    
$V136 = $_POST["part7q6"];    
$V137 = $_POST["part7q7"];    
$V138 = $_POST["part7q8"];    
$V139 = $_POST["part8q1"];    
$V140 = $_POST["part8q2"];    
$V141 = $_POST["part8q3"];    
$V142 = $_POST["part8q4"];    
$V143 = $_POST["part8q5"];    
$V144 = $_POST["part8q6"];    
$currenttime = date("Ymd h:m:sa");    
$server = "***";    
$connOptions = array("Database"=>"**", "UID"=>"**", "PWD"=>"**!");    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connOptions);    

if($conn){    
    $query="INSERT INTO dbo.profile (    
        name,    
        email,    
        company,    
        telephone,    
        worktitle,    
        industry,    
        createdate    
        )    
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,getdate())";    
    $params = array(    
        $name,    
        $email,    
        $company,    
        $contact,    
        $worktitle,    
        $industry,      
        $currenttime    
        );    
    if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params)){    
        echo "<h4>Thank you</h4><p>You have completed the survey and your     answers have been received.</p>";    
    } else {    
        echo "<p>We're sorry but there has been and error receiving your     answers.</p>";    
    }    
} else {    
    echo "<p>We're sorry but there has been and error receiving your answers.    </p>";    
}
```

**Im trying to insert records to another table like this continuing from the previous line:**

```
if($conn){    
$query1="INSERT INTO dbo.SurveyResponse (    
        profileid,    
        Value,    
        CreatedOn    
        )    
VALUES ('2', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,getdate())";    
    $params=array($V101,$currenttime);    

$query1="INSERT INTO dbo.SurveyResponse (    
        profileid,    
        Value,    
        CreatedOn    
        )    
VALUES ('2', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,getdate())";    
    $params=array($V102,$currenttime);    

    $query1="INSERT INTO dbo.SurveyResponse (    
        profileid,    
        Value,    
        CreatedOn    
        )    
VALUES ('2', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,getdate())";    
    $params=array($V103,$currenttime);    

.    .    .    .    .    
if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, $params))        
{    
        echo "<h4>Thank you</h4><p>You have completed the survey and your     answers have been received.</p>";    
    } else {    
        echo "<p>We're sorry but there has been and error receiving your     answers.</p>";    
    }    
} else {    
    echo "<p>We're sorry but there has been and error receiving your answers.    </p>";    
}    

?>
```

***I have been trying this, insert works for first table but not the second table, can anyone help please***

Comment: Take a look at what your code is doing. You keep overwriting the `$query1` variable, what do you think will happen?

Comment: See also http://php.net/sqlsrv_query#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-query-notes

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mike, I tired to separate them this way

Comment: if($conn){
$query1="INSERT INTO dbo.SurveyResponse (
  profileid,
  Value,
  CreatedOn
  )
VALUES ('2', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,getdate())";
 $params1=array($V101,$currenttime);

if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, $params1))
{
  echo "<h4>Thank you</h4>
 } else {
  echo "<p>...
 }
}

if($conn){
$query2="INSERT INTO dbo.SurveyResponse (
  profileid,
  Value,
  CreatedOn
  )
VALUES ('2', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,getdate())";
if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, $params1))
{
  echo "<h4>Thank you</h4>
 } else {
  echo "<p>...
 }}

Comment: this question looks like it could use some editing, you should consider adding only the code relative to the question. I suggest reading the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to enter multiple records to second table. Thanks to Miken32

```
if($conn){
    $query1="INSERT INTO dbo.SurveyResponse (
            profileid,
            Qid,
            Value,
            CreatedOn
            )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?,getdate())";
        $params1=array(2,101,$V101,$currenttime);

    if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, $params1))
    {
            echo "";
        } 
        else { echo"<p>We're sorry but there has been and error receiving your answers.</p>" ; }
        }


    if($conn){
    $query2="INSERT INTO dbo.SurveyResponse (
            profileid,
            Qid,
            Value,
            CreatedOn
            )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?,getdate())";
        $params2=array(2,102,$V102,$currenttime);

    if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2, $params2))
    {
            echo "";
        } 
        else { echo"<p>We're sorry but there has been and error receiving your answers.</p>" ; }
        }
```